# Configure Highstock export server in Play framework (java) 1.2.5

Tags: java, highcharts, playframework-1.x

Currently am using Highstock 2.0.4 to render the graph on UI. But problem is am using this application in Offline mode. In Offline mode the graph is not exported because it sends a request to hichart.export server. I want to  configure Export server in play framework 1.2.5(java). 
Am using:

1. Java 1.7
2. play framework 1.2.5
3. Highstock 2.0.4
4. jquery 1.7.2

Comment: What exactly is the question, I can't really figure out what you are trying to do?

Comment: wants to configure export server,

Answer (score 0):

So you need to setup your own exporting server.

Docs:
- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, In the given link "download the source for the export-server module from Github. This is a maven module", But my project is not a Maven project, i dont have access to internet to download it dependencies.